# Constructor vs. Factory in .NET Framework

Tags: .net, design-patterns, factory-pattern

Below is an article about .net framework's use of patterns. I'm not sure I understand the bolded part in the excerpt below.  Is it implying if you change the details of creating the object, you (might) change the constructor arguments?

> There are many cases in the Framework where you
>   can obtain a new instance of a struct or class
>   without calling its constructor yourself. The
>   System.Convert class contains a host of static
>   methods that work like this. To convert an integer
>   to a Boolean, for example, you can call
>   Convert.ToBoolean and pass in the integer. The
>   return value of this method call is a new Boolean
>   set to "true" if the integer was non-zero and
>   "false" otherwise. The Convert class creates the
>   Boolean for you with the correct value. Other type
>   conversion methods work similarly. The Parse
>   methods on Int32 and Double return new instances
>   of those objects set to the appropriate value
>   given only a string.
>
> This strategy for creating new object instances is
>   known as a Factory pattern. Rather than invoking
>   the object's constructor, you can ask the object
>   factory to create the instance for you. That way,
>   the factory class can hide the complexity of
>   object creation (like how to parse a Double out of
>   a string). If you wanted to change the details of
>   creating the object, you'd only have to change the
>   factory itself; **you would not have to change every
>   single place in the code where the constructor is
>   called.**

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188707.aspx.

Comment: Good question - isn't the alternative to a factory a *new constructor*? (As opposed to duplicating parsing code throughout your codebase.) Constructors can also "hide the complexity of object creation (like how to parse a Double out of a string)."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually think that the examples they've provided are not necessarily great examples.

The Factory pattern becomes more useful in .NET when you're constructing classes.  For example, look at the [WebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx).

This class is normally instantiated by calling:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
```

The [WebRequest.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.create.aspx) method uses the Factory pattern.  Depending on the type of URL, it will create a different type (subclass) of WebRequest.  If you pass it an `http://` url, for example, you will actually create an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) instance - an `ftp://` URL will create an [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx).

By using the Factory pattern here, more URL types can be added later without changing any code on the client side - you just pass in the different URL (as a string), and get a new object.

Comment: You're talking about factory method pattern. But original question refers to factory pattern (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_pattern ), that covers both factory method pattern and abstract factory pattern I described below.

Answer (score 2):

The Factory Pattern is the one that I use the most on my programs. It can be very helpful on certain cases, but you should certainly be careful when using it. *If your factory looks like a constructor overload, then it probably should be a constructor overload.* The examples that were given by the MSDN article aren't good. In fact, it has been my belief for quite some time that objects like Int, String, etc., don't contemplate overloads for each other because they are **structs** rather than classes and, as a rule, struct constructors should not throw exceptions (which would happen if, for example, you could feed a "hello world" to a int). But I assumed that.

There are, of course, lots of place around the web where you can find better explanations of when to use the factory pattern and its benefits. The example given by Reed is one of the best and follows my rule for using Factories: I use factories when I have a class hierarchy or a number of classes that implement a certain interface and I want to build one of those objects but receive an object of the superclass/interface rather than the object itself. That way, the object that's calling the factory **doesn't have to worry about implementation details**. It knows that it's expecting an object of a certain class, and that's what it gets, even if it's a cast.

In the current application I'm building (a program generator), I need to parse a datatable SQL definition. I use a home-brew parser to do that. Each time the parser encounters a variable ("IDENTIFIER VARIABLE-TYPE"), I call a factory and pass the string to it. The factory then checks the variable-type substring and returns to me a **SqlVariable**, that could actually be an **IntegerSqlVariable** or a **CharSqlVariable**.

The main parser object doesn't know what variable it got. It pushes the SqlVariable to a list and reads the next line. Of course, I could have a single class to deal with all variable types; I personally choose not to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea of factory seems different. It's not just about hiding the complexity of implementation, it's about inversion of control as well (IoC).

- Instead of creating `Sender` and `Receiver` objects your own, let's make `MessageFactory` object responsible for creating them.
- Let's imagine initially we implemented a `TcpMessageFactory` (`MessageFactory` descendant) creating `TcpSender` and `TcpReceiver` objects. So now our application works with TCP.
- A bit later we discovered that UDP is faster. So we implemented `UdpSender` and `UdpReciever`. Moreover, we implemented `UdpMessageFactory` (`MessageFactory` descendant as well)
- Now we can allow user to choose which protocol to use. Based on this, we create our factory object (either `TcpMessageFactory` or `UdpMessageFactory`) and use it in our application further.

In this example `MessageFactory.CreateSender` and `MessageFactory.CreateReciever` must be abstract methods; methods of `Sender` & `Reciever` forming their public API (contract) must be abstract as well.

Btw, initially factories were used mainly for object creation: imagine C++ library (DLL) that must allow to create a set of its own types to the main .exe. Passing the instances between different modules there is almost impossible, because their structure depends on a particular compiler. But it's possible to pass the interfaces. So such DLL should:

- Export a function returning factory interface, e.g. `IDllTypeFactory`
- The object implementing it must return `IDllTypeXxx` objects on invocation of its `CreateXxx` methods. These `IDllTypeXxx` are actually implemented by the types we originally planned to export.

But as you know, .NET with its unified assembly format makes it possible to pass the objects between different modules. Moreover, reflection allows to create a type you don't know at all. So factories in .NET are used more rarely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use constructor overloads to change the constructor without having to alter every area in the source code but that will quickly lead to a ridiculous number of constructors if you aren't very careful.

I think the general idea of the article is hiding the implementation rather than necessarily preventing massive constructor overloads in order to account for constructor changes. The idea being the object shouldn't have knowledge of how it can be constructed.

In the example given, you don't want to clog your Int class with how it could become an int from a string or a double so you create your Factory whose sole responsibility is to create X object from Y parameters.

I would definitely suggest the Head First Design Patterns book as a good intro to learning Design Patterns. The examples are Java based but the logic behind them applies no matter what language you are using.

Comment: Ridiculous number of constructors, and "massive constructor overloads", or ridiculous number of factory methods, and "massive factory method overloads"? It's all the same. You're not going to "clog your Int class", there's plenty of room in there.